# How can I get the diff detail (display whole file) of two version by use SharpSVN?

Tags: diff, sharpsvn

SVNClient.diff method seems just can get the differences result, and it would not show all the code. 
All I want is to compare two versions like SVN show.

PS: Does method GetDiffSummary just show the summary status(modified, delete, etc...) of each version?
And it would not show the detail line change, right?

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve each of the revisions separately (you already know the URL & revision numbers) & display them in your application.

`SVNClient.Diff()` asks the *server* to calculate the difference. What you're getting *is* the "diff detail" because that's all that's changed.

You could also use [`SVNClient.Blame()`](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/M_SharpSvn_SvnClient_Blame_1.htm) to get an annotation of who last changed which lines, and at which revisions.

Comment: Thanks alroc. But SVNClient.Blame() can't compare two special versions, and it doesn't display the changes...

Comment: I didn't say that it would compare two versions. As for "display", that's up to the application you're writing. SharpSVN is just the API to get at the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to both versions of the file (to provide/generate the diff yourself) you can use .Write() to fetch a single version... and do that twice. This is what tools like TortoiseSVN do to show their visual diff.